SVG element not displaying in production mode
I'm facing an issue with viewing the svg elements in production mode, it worked totally fine in development mode (localhost). Me and my team are suspecting it is the issue with the gulp.
<img src="assets/logo.svg" alt="Logo">

gulp.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const inline = require('gulp-inline');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('default', function(done) {
gulp.src('../../dist/apps/index.html')
    .pipe(inline({
        base: 'public/',
        js: function() { return uglify(); },
        css: function() { return minifyCss().pipe(autoprefixer()); }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../../dist/apps/template'));

// Put your default task code here
done();
});


This is the error I am getting from console

Do you get any error in the console? If yes, please share the screenshot

@Viji_Pykara thank you, I've already added the screenshot of the error from the console. It says FILE_NOT_FOUND

Could you please try like this:

No, I tried and the filepath doesn't seem to be the problem, because it worked just fine in developer mode

when you write
<img src="assets/logo.svg" alt="Logo">

Angular look for the image acording the "baseRef" value.
If you have:
<base href="/"> //from "https://your_dominio/assets"
<base href="/custom"> //from "https://your_dominio/custom/assets"

It's strange search from file:///c:
